# Why cannot see any code completion after imported an EmberObject extension into a different file, using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, visual-studio-code, code-completion

As already explained in the title, I can't see any code completion after imported an EmberObject extension

- file form.js:

  ```
  import EmberObject from '@ember/object'; 

  const Form = EmberObject.extend({
          isTouched: false,
          isValid: false,
          errors: null,
          value: null,
          init() {...},
          getSomething(){ ... }  
  }
  ```
- file component.js

  ```
  import Form from '../../classes/form';

  init() {        
   this._super(arguments);        
   // console.log(this.elementId);        
   this.form = Form.create({          
       email: [this.email, Validators.required, Validators.email],
       password: [this.password, Validators.required]         
   });
  }
  ```

at this point in component.js when I type **this.form.** the editor (VSC) doesn't give me any real suggestion on Form class/EmberObject

Any guess?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Ember objects are difficult for editors to understand.

However, you can use native classes, which will improve your editor experience!

Here's an oveview article on how to get going: https://medium.com/build-addepar/es-classes-in-ember-js-63e948e9d78e

The TL:DR; is

1. Install Ember Decorators https://github.com/ember-decorators/ember-decorators
2. Use a native classes

In your example it would be

```
import EmberObject from '@ember/object'
export default class FormClass extends EmberObject {
  constructor() {
    // replaces init
    super();
  doStuff() { }
```

Later
    let form = new FormClass();